# Prove that we can divide student in k groups

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

There are 3 clubs. Each club includes exactly k students and each student in one club has atleast $\dfrac{3k}{4}$ friends and in each of the 2 other clubs (i.e. $\frac{3k}{4}$ in one club and $\frac{3k}{4}$ in other one as well).

Prove that we can divide $3\cdot k$ students in k groups of size $3$ ,such that in each group all of the students be friend with each other.

---

My attempt:

I tried counting in two ways , and my other attempt was to consider two groups and prove there is a perfect matching between each of them(there is and its proven) and try to build those k groups which leads to nothing:)

Comment: What have you tried/found? Please visit our [help](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i tried counting in two ways , and my other attempt was to consider two groups and prove there is a perfect matching between each of them(there is and its proven) and try to build those k groups which ledto nothing:)

Comment: does anyone have any idea?

Comment: I have an idea. It's based on probability. Initially there are k=4*p students in each group..(obviously), then find the probability that 3 persons know each other. If it is non zero, consider it, and remove them from the set., now we have (4p-1)*3 persons. Again find the probability, and iterate over and over. At the last step, you'll find that the probability of 3 persons knowing each other is exactly 1. That's when it gets proved. (I used this as an algorithmic idea, so can be proved using induction)

Comment: i believe that we cant use induction , by deleting 3 vertices who know each other , it changes the degree of the vertices in a remaining graph and im kind of sure it can be solved by matching

Answer (score 3):

Use Hall's theorem to find a perfect matching $M$ between two clubs.

Then, form a bipartite graph where one side is the third club, and the other side is the $k$ edges of $M$, where a student of the third club is adjacent to an edge of $M$ if the student is friends with both endpoints.

Apply Hall's theorem again, this time to this bipartite graph.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, but I can't supply the details.  How do we know there's a perfect matching between two clubs?  I know that a $d$-regular balanced bipartite graph has a perfect matching, but that isn't true if we only know that each vertex has degree at least $d$.  I don't see how to get the second perfect matching even if the graphs are regular.  How does one see that Hall's condition holds?  Can you help me?

Comment: @saulspatz The key lemma is that a subgraph of $K_{n,n}$ with minimum degree $\frac n2$ has a perfect matching. We check Hall's condition in two steps: first, for $|S| \le \frac n2$ (in which case the minimum degree condition gives us $|N(S)| \ge |S|$) and seccond, for $|S| > \frac n2$ (in which case $|N(S)| = n \ge |S|$).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much, there is the second part in details, the second graph has 2 part A and B with k vertices(assume A the part that represent k edges of the first matching)
and the degree of every vertex in part A , is at least k/2
because considering the 2 vertices, they have at least k/2 common neighbors in the third club
3*k/4 * 2 - k = k/2
and bipartite graph with k vertices in its 2 part which every vertex has degree at least k/2 has perfect matching